# Как остановить audio в HTML (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, аудио

После `var audio = new Audio('test.mp3')` и `audio.play()` аудиозапись начинает играть, но вместо того, что-бы остановить аудиозапись на `audio.pause()`, страница перезагружается.

Как остановить воспроизведение аудио?

Comment: вы создаете ДОМ узел через класс Audio? и если так, покажите как он выглядит

Comment: Нужен код, который Вы написали, для большего понимания